# How to give two names to the same enum? (Type Name Alias)

Tags: c#

I got a need for two exactly identical enums with different names

I can do

```
enum DoorStatus{Open,Closed,Locked,Broken};
enum WindowStatus{Open,Closed,Locked,Broken};
```

and will probably be bit easier to read.

but I'd rather not duplicate code

in C++ I'd do

```
typedef Door,Window;
```

what is the solution in C#?

and why have both you ask?
I got Application That Handles a `Window`
application that handles a `Door`.

I want the `Window` application developer to send me data using 'WindowStatus' enum
the 'Door' guy use 'DoorStatus' enum.

I believe that user should know or care I got other devices that can be abstracted similarly.

EDIT: used

```
enum HatchStatus{Open,Closed,Locked,Broken};
using DoorStatus = HatchStatus;
using WndowStatus = HatchStatus;
```

EDIT2:

Error A using clause must precede all other elements defined in the namespace except extern alias declarations

:(

Comment: I don't know an easy way to do this, but do you mind me asking . . . why would you want to?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you just want an alias, you can use a `using` directive:

```
using Enum2 = Enum1;
```

Comment: +1 I'm ashamed to say that I didn't know you could alias a type as well as a namespace.  I guess it's because I've never had to, since I can't see why you'd duplicate a type under a different name; unless you've replaced one with another during a code upgrade/review or something. And then it'd be temporary I'd hope!

Comment: @AndrasZoltan: It makes more sense if you have types that exist in 2 namespaces that are used, e.g. `System.Timer` and `Windows.Forms.Timer`. Rather than fully qualify it each time, just create an alias.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett that's true - yes - that's actually very useful.

Comment: @Thomas Levsque 
A using clause must precede all other elements defined in the namespace except extern alias declarations

so It Does't really work for enums.

Comment: @NahumLitvin In light of the fact that you're trying to create what appears to be another type, like typedef, for use by other code; thomas' answer isn't suitable (he wasn't to know that at the time).  Also, an alias is file-and-namespace scope and just syntactic sugar it's not actually creating a type. Every file in which you wish to be able to use the alias needs to have a `using` in it - making it 'horribly complex' to use across a whole system.

Comment: worked light charm. "Enum2" can be any random name of choosing, Enum1 is the actual enum to redirect to.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose the question is if you have two different enums that have the exact same values - then why keep both at all?

The best solution is to pick one and refactor everything to use just one.

### Update

Now that you've updated your example, I think you should consider whether an enum is actually the best solution.

```
public class ObjectState
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
}//should really be immutable
 //should also implement IEquatable<ObjectState> for equality

public static readonly State_Open = new ObjectState()
  { ID = 1, Description = "Open" }
public static readonly State_Closed = new ObjectState() 
  { ID = 2, Description = "Closed" }

public static class DoorStatus
{ 
   public static readonly ObjectState Open = State_Open;
   public static readonly ObjectState Closed = State_Closed; 
}
//and WindowStatus if you want.


public class Door {
  public ObjectState State { get; set; }
} //or perhaps refactor to a shared base/interface StatefulObject
```

Now you can simply do:

```
new Door() { State = DoorStatus.Open; }
```

If you also implement `IEquatable<ObjectState>` then you can compare the equality of two object's state as well; you'd then likely implement `GetHashCode` as well meaning you can also use a state as a key in a grouping or dictionary.

The good thing now is that both an open window and an open door now have exactly the same state that equate directly, rather than using some syntactic sugar to get around a design that required identical enums.

### Final Update

Since the above is 'horribly complex' - despite being, I think, good design; the best you can do is ensure that two separate enums at least share the same underlying values for identical states:

```
public enum States
{
  Open
}

public enum DoorStates
{
  Open = States.Open
}

public enum WindowStates
{
  Open = States.Open
}
```

Ultimately if you're using an enum you cannot get around the need to have two separately defined ones - this solution simply means that `Open` is equal for any object that can be in an `Open` state.

Comment: I think Andras is right. If you have 2 times the same think you need to revieuw the construction and make it more abstract. OO-languages are made to reuse stuff we have written so we don't have duplicated code

Comment: Okay - well, IMHO you're drastically reducing the readability and expandability of your code by cloning a type using `using`.  It's just not good design.

Comment: @NahumLitvin - I've had one other idea you could use (see 'Final Update'.  I actually really don't like it - but it might suit your needs up to a point.